# Determinant of a Hankel matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, hankel-matrices

Is there a closed form for determinant of the Hankel matrix of the sequence $\{ 1, a, a^2, \dots, a^{2n+2} \}$?

Comment: Why does the sequence run up to $2n+2$?

Comment: Please post your second question as a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I interpret your question correctly, then I suggest that you multiply the first row by $a$ and subtract it from the second row. The determinant of the resulting matrix should be easy to calculate.